# Meteor: collection helpers or transform on FS.Collection?

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper, collectionfs

With dburles:collection-helpers package you can add collection helpers on any Mongo.collection. But I can't do that on FS.Collection. I get **TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'helpers'**. Transform function doesn't work either.

```
var createUploader = function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    fileObj.uploadedBy = Meteor.users.find({_id: fileObj.uploader});
    readStream.pipe(writeStream);
};
Photos = new FS.Collection("photos", {
    stores: [
        new FS.Store.GridFS("photos", {transformWrite: createUploader})
    ],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*']
        }
    }
});
```

Can't do this? Notice when a photo is inserted from the client `FS.File` gets `userId`, hence `fileObj.uploadedBy = Meteor.users.find({_id: fileObj.uploader});`

Comment: In the CollectionFS doc, says **underlying Mongo.Collection instance available through myFSCollection.files** missed that part. But still get error: **Error: [Can't apply helpers to 'cfs.photos.filerecord' a transform function already exists!]**

Comment: I just discovered https://atmospherejs.com/maximum/multi-transform which may help you apply helper-like transforms to your collectionfs instances.

Answer (score 0):

matb33-collection-helpers package works by applying a transform function to a collection. CollectionFS already has its own transform function applied, therefore you cannot overwrite that with ones from the collection helpers package.

As suggested at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/526#issuecomment-71944535)

> Since CFS already applies a transform, it would not be a good idea to use collection helpers. You should be able to do pretty much the same thing by extending the FS.File prototype with your own functions, though.

You could define custom functions on the prototype. The prototype will have access to other properties of the doc through `this` so you would basically have the same functionality with collection helpers.

Another option would be to store the file related information on the individual file object during the insert as metadata such as:

```
Template.photoUploadForm.events({
  'change .photoInput': function(event, template) {
    FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
      var newPhoto = new FS.File(file);
      newPhoto.metadata = {uploadedBy: Meteor.user().profile.name};
      Photos.insert(newPhoto, function (err, fileObj) {
        if (!err) console.log(fileObj._id + " inserted!")
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Your code can also be rewritten to implement a `beforeWrite` filter instead of a transformWrite as in

```
Photos = new FS.Collection("photos", {
    stores: [
        new FS.Store.GridFS("photos", {
          beforeWrite: function (fileObj) {
            fileObj.metadata = {uploadedBy: Meteor.user().profile.name};
          }
        })
    ],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*']
        }
    }
});
```

Finally, you can opt to storing the ID of the user and publishing a reactive join

```
Photos = new FS.Collection("photos", {
    stores: [
        new FS.Store.GridFS("photos", {
          beforeWrite: function (fileObj) {
            fileObj.metadata = {
              uploadedBy: Meteor.userId()
            };
          }
        })
    ],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*']
        }
    }
});
```

And for the publication, you can use `reywood:publish-composite`

```
Meteor.publishComposite('photosWithUsers', function() {
  return {
    find: function() {
      return Photos.find();
    },
    children: [
      {
        find: function(photo) {
          return Meteor.users.find(photo.uploadedBy, {
            fields: {username: 1, 'profile.name': 1}
          });
        }
      }
    ]
  };
});
```

Of course on the client, you need to subscribe to the `photosWithUsers` publication.

Now to access that information in the client, since you cannot apply a transform or a helper on the collectionFS documents, you can create a global template helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('getUsername', function(userId) {
  check(userId, String);
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
  return user && user.profile.name + ' (' + user.username + ')';
});
```

Now you can use that helper in your templates:

```
<template name="somePhoto">
  {{#with FS.GetFile "Photos" photo}}
    <img src="{{url}}" alt="This photo has been uploaded by {{getUsername uploadedBy}}"> 
  {{/with}}
</template>

Template.somePhoto.helpers({
  photo: function() {
    return Photos.findOne();
  }
})
```

Comment: I edited my question with the code I have which doesn't work. How do you extend FS.File prototype though? any example I can look at?

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the *metadata* solution you seem to be seeking.

Comment: Sorry for late reply I only have limited time and use of Computer. Your code is inserting file object with `userId` as `uploadedBy` metadata. which I already did. But on the fs collection I am trying to do `transform` based on that `userId` and get user's data(the one who uploaded). Like this `fileObj.uploader = Meteor.users.find({_id: fileObj.uploadedBy}); return fileObj;`. So on the template I can do `uploader.profile.name` to get name of the user instead of id. Obviously I'am failing this

Comment: I added my own answer, it works. But I really wanted to know the hard way and will look further into it. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Zaya I've updated the answer so that we now store the name instead of the userId, or if you want you can store both.

Comment: Sure we can store both. I tried that already. That's not updating reactively though, since I can't do something like collection helper on fs collection. The `profile.name` is stuck there and it won't update when user changes `profile.name`. I don't think it's good joining collections by field other than the `id`.

Comment: @Zaya I've updated the answer with reactive publish and join

Comment: This is similar to my answer. But I like your global template helper. I will update my code thanks.

Comment: It is actually a lot different because your answer assumes that the user document is published to the client. Mine actually publishes the exact user that's needed on the client for a given photo. And only the required fields. That's a huge difference in Meteor world.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know this is not the not-so-easy solution I was looking for. Since I am using publish-composite package. I can just publish users' data(only profile field) with photos. And on the client I can do template helper like this:

```
Template.photo.helpers({
    photoUploader: function() {
        var currentPhoto = Photos.findOne();
        var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: currentPhoto.uploader});
        return user.profile.name;
    },
});
```

and

```
<template name="photos">
    {{#each photos}}
      {{> photo}}
    {{/each}}
    ...
```

then

```
<template name="photo">
  {{photoUploader}}
  ...
```