# Meteor: Reactive update, cascaded delete/update. Normalizing vs Denormalizing

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper, meteor-collections

How to do cascaded delete, update and reactive update in existing joined documents? Say for example I join `Posts` collection with `Meteor.users` collection with `userId()` as author. I could do transform function on the `Posts` collection to get user data of the author, like `username` and display `username` of the author on any post. The problem is when user changes his/her `username`, existing posts won't update author's `username` reactively. And when you delete parent document child documents are still there. I used popular smart packages like `publish-composite` and `collection-helpers` but problem still exists. Any expert meteor dev can help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: This question is to general to be answered. You need to state your problem more clearly and probably narrow it down to a single topic.

Comment: Sorry, I posted this on meteor forums, more appropriate place. Right now I am looking at this smart package called collection-hooks. Looks like it will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use collection-hooks to solve this problem, the following pseudo code should get you going:

```
// run only on the server where we have access to the complete dataset
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.users.after.update(function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {
    var oldUsername = this.previous.username;
    var newUsername = doc.username;
    // don't bother running this hook if username has not changed
    if (oldUsername !== newUsername) {
      Posts.update({
        // find the user and make sure you don't overselect those that have already been updated
        author: userId, 
        authorUsername: oldUsername
      }, {$set: {
        // set the new username
        authorUsername: newUsername
      }}, {
        // update all documents that match
        multi: true
      })
    }
  }, {fetchPrevious: true});
}
```

Comment: Amazing. I got publish-composite, collection-hooks and collection-helpers all working together nicely. But I don't understand why I can't use collection-helpers or transform function on FS.Collection. CollectionFS doc says you can do that on underlying Mongo.Collection. Thought **MyCollectionFS.files.helpers({})** would work but it doesn't. Anyways, thank you so much.

Comment: no problem. if the current answer works for you, you can let everybody know by marking it accepted. don't hesitate to post another question for the CollectionFS problem, too.

Comment: I posted question for that here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444401/meteor-collection-helpers-or-transform-on-fs-collection